# Not getting 'Page Not Found' with JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6

I'm trying with Javaee6 with GlassFish3.1.
I created a web project (with JSF2.0), with only one file, **one.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>ONE</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="oneForm">
        <h:commandButton id="oneButton" value="To Two" action="two" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I've not added web.xml, as it is optional for javaee6.
I added **faces-config.xml**, so that default servlet mapping works. (with only top element)

```
<faces-config version="2.0" .../>
```

When I hit command-button on the page, I'm expecting 'Page Not Found' error. But the page just reloads. If I actually put file two.xhtml, it works correctly, but in it's absence, **does not give error**, which I'm expecting.

Am I missing something, some config?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. JSF works with so-called navigation cases. If it doesn't find a matching case, it will just postback to the same view. This is specified in the [JSF 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) (pick the one for evaluation).

> ### 7.4.2 Default NavigationHandler Algorithm
>
> ...
>
> The default NavigationHandler implementation must behave as if it were performing the following algorithm (although optimized implementation techniques may be utilized):
>
> - **If no navigation case is matched by a call to the `handleNavigation()` method, this is an indication that the current view should be redisplayed.** As of JSF 2.0, a null outcome does not unconditionally cause all navigation rules to be
>     skipped.
> - ...

However, when you set the JSF project stage to *Development* by a context parameter in `web.xml`,

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>  
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

then clicking the button should then result in a development warning message in the postback,

> - Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/one.xhtml' for action 'two' with outcome 'two'

so that eventual developer mistakes are at least put in attention.